# default.properties file in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on android app , I opened my project on eclipse after a day to continue my work but default.properties file is automatically deleted.

And now I am getting this error on console.

```
project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
```

Please tell me how can I recovered it.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project?  `project -> clean`

Comment: What about copying the file from a different project to this one and clean the project before running it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the question comments:

- Copy the `default.properties` file from a different project to this one.
- Clean the project before running it .